# how to style a-tags nested in div with id using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm used to JQuery but not to pure Javascript.
I have this:

```
document.getElementById("div-id a").style.javascript_property = "color: red;";
```

OF COURSE it doesn't work.
What i want is that all a-tags in one specific div with an id='div-id' to become red.

in jquery i would write:

```
$('#div-id a').css('color', 'red');
```

But i need it in pure js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
var div = document.getElementById("div-id");
var list = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementById` method takes a string representing an **id**, not a selector. The clue is in the name. The `querySelectorAll` method takes a string representing a selector, but it returns a nodeList, so you would have to loop over it like an array.

The property name which you have called `javascript_property` needs to match the CSS property name (with hyphenated-words turned into camelCase) (so it should be `"color"`).

The value you give it needs to match the CSS properties value, not the entire rule (so `"red"`).

None of this, however, is pure JavaScript. It is DOM (except for `querySelectorAll` which is from the Selectors API).